# Getting the value of an attribute in C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, textbox, placeholder

I have several textboxes that dynamically add placeholder text and later on in my code I wish to retrieve that text from each textbox. Below is an example of a text box:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder=""></asp:TextBox>
```

Later on in the code I wish to have something like this (psudocode):

```
string firstname = tbFirstname.placerholderText;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkeesb2c.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 You're welcome.

Comment: @Bauss But MSDN not providing any examples

Comment: The link has an example??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer it by the attribute name

```
string firstname = tbFirstname.Attributes["placeholder"];
```

or set the placeholder value

```
tbFirstName.Attributes["placeholder"]="Some text";
```

That should work fine for HTML Server controls as well.